# How to check if you written same numbers for two times in int input?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, random, input, while-loop

```
import random

purpose = random.randint(1, 10)
attempts = []
guess = int(input("Try to guess number between 1 to 10: "))
guess2 = guess + guess

    
while purpose != guess:
    print ("Oh sorry your guess was wrong :( ")
    attempts.append (guess)
    guess = int(input("Try to guess again: "))
```

> there I want to make that if you guessed same number for two times, for example guesses were [5, 4, 4, 7]- program writes "you have a short memory".
> I tried it with function but code just writes "<function short_memory at 0x7fa6d7e58430>" (short_memory was name of function)
> There is function:

```
def short_memory ():  
  if guess2 == guess ** 2:
     print ("you already guessed that number, you have a short memory")
```

> I know it's a little bit messed up but I don't know how to do that
> There is the end of the program:

```
if purpose == guess :
    print ("Your guess was right!! ")


print ("your attempts was: ", attempts)
```

Comment: This usually comes (not error) if you don't add `()` at the end of the function name; you're not calling it. Can you also include the code that you tried? Please read [mcve].

Comment: I added a function, but it's not working